# How to include small x button in textfield in Extjs

Tags: search, extjs, textfield

I would like to override 'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel' in a way that I have small clickable button in textfield to clear its value.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There are different ways to achieve this with override, plugin.. or adding appropriate 'beforerender' event handler:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224'
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234'
            }, {
                name: 'Homer',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244'
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                // HERE IS THE CODE
                beforerender: function (grid) {
                    var searchField = this.down('textfield[name=searchField]');
                    searchField.setTriggers({
                        reset: {
                            cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
                            hidden: true,
                            handler: function () {
                                this.setValue('')
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    searchField.on('change', function(searchField, value) {
                        searchField.getTrigger('reset').setHidden(Ext.isEmpty(value));
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the following sample the 'Reset' trigger will be hidden when the search field value is empty.

Comment: Thank you Arthur. It works, although I have no idea how. I am beginner and I am trying to figure out how I can combine multiple components, but I am probably thinking in an old-fashioned manner. Could you please tell me how for example I can add a button in the middle of a panel, so that I can listen for onclick event and then do something in the controller (for example console.log('I've been clicked');)? I know how I can add button in panel header, but I would like to have it inside the panel, just as you made this button in the textfield.

Comment: There are several ways to do it. As a rule I extend 'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel' and override the initComponent method adding appropriate controls and registering handlers of the controller. ExtJs using standard OOP patterns (plugins, mixins.. extends and overrides) to change the behavior of the classes.